# Why there is no static files(js/css/pic) in my Django(1.5.1) Admin Site?

Tags: python, css, django

I am learning Django on "The Django Book(http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html)" these days, when I launched the Admin Site according to the tutorial, there was only html and I found that there were two 500 responses via Chrome:

GET 127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/base.css 500 (Internal Server Error)

GET 127.0.0.1:8000/static/admin/css/login.css 500 (Internal Server Error)

So I googled this problem and get many many many useless(for me) solutions, such as set the STATIC_ROOT in settings.py, then "python manage.py collectstatic"; or set the ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX in the settings.py(Actually there is no ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX in 1.5.1)......but all of these solutions were not useful for me, it still get 500.

I have uncommented 'django.contrib.staticfiles' in INSTALLED_APPS according to the Django Book previously. What can I do else now?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: follow this [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/) page

Comment: @RickyA I change the Django version to 1.5.4, and it is solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve this problem by myself.

The reason is not caused by Django version or settings in settings.py, **but by the key(s) which is(are) not ASCII in Windows regedit**.

The regedit path is **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type**, find out the non-ASCII key(s)(such as Chinese keys) and delete it(them).

It works now:)